# Python build package error- 'virtualenv' has no attribute 'cli_run'

Tags: python, build, package, databricks, azure-databricks

Using Azure Databricks to build a python package. Received the following error from command:

```
python3 -m build

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/build/__main__.py", line 214, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:], 'python -m build')
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/build/__main__.py", line 206, in main
    build_package(args.srcdir, outdir, distributions, config_settings, not args.no_isolation, args.skip_dependencies)
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/build/__main__.py", line 94, in build_package
    _build_in_isolated_env(builder, outdir, distributions, config_settings)
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/build/__main__.py", line 52, in _build_in_isolated_env
    with IsolatedEnvBuilder() as env:
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/build/env.py", line 65, in __enter__
    executable, scripts_dir = _create_isolated_env_virtualenv(self._path)
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/build/env.py", line 156, in _create_isolated_env_virtualenv
    result = virtualenv.cli_run(cmd, setup_logging=False)
AttributeError: module 'virtualenv' has no attribute 'cli_run'
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve the same issue (although in an AWS environment) by upgrading pip and virtualenv:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip virtualenv
```